# gather 10 json requests before doing 1 mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to figure out a way to collect emails from 10 json requests before I do 1 insert.
so 
step 1 - insertemails.php will receive emails through a json post
step 2 - it will save? record it ? somewhere and keep a count
step 3 - when the count reaches 10 emails it will do 1 mysql query:
insert into table (id, email) values (), () , () etc...
let me know your thoughts. I can do it by writing the emails into a text file then count how many lines or use a different separator.
But I was looking for something better/safer ? since text files are readable.
Let me know if you have any suggestions thank you !

Comment: What is the purpose of waiting for 10 posts? Is there something specific you are trying to achieve by this?

Comment: I need it done in this manner that's the school assignment. I am not looking for code just a way to do it , i ll w rite my own code

Comment: If the program will be running the whole time just store them as an array, the only reason you would need a text file is if you had to stop execution and then resume and pick up where you left off

Comment: You're going to have to store data either way. Why not just keep the emails separated under a temporary table and then move them once you reach an amount of rows you like?

Comment: @IanSellar well the requests come as json one by one, each "website visitor" will enter his/her email and it needs to be logged somehow until there are 10 available then do 1 insert into table

Comment: @LifeQuery well this will be "used for a hypothetical site with hundreds of thousands of visits per day"

Comment: @LifeQuery we want to avoid using mysql until there are 10. that's pretty much the requirement

Comment: @fogsy OK, can you go for a no noSQL solution?

Comment: @LifeQuery which one ? mongodb ? I thought about it